# Present variable information within a single mturk HIT

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'd like to use mturk to have 10 workers visit my website, log in with a test account, and enter some information on their profile. I don't want them to see each other's entries, so each worker should get login information for a different test account when they view the HIT.

This almost looks like what mturk's template feature is for -- I could upload a CSV with the information for each test account. But if I understand correctly, that will make 10 separate HITs, and allow one worker to do all 10 of them. **Is there any way to have mturk put information that varies between workers into a single HIT?**

Here are the solutions I'm currently aware of:

1. Use the CLI to automate creation of a bunch of different HITs. This would be a lot of work, and also make approving and retrieving the results cumbersome.
2. Direct workers to a survey website that's capable of doing what I want, and have them get the login information there.
3. Dynamically fill in part of the HIT using an AJAX request to an external website and database. That seems like crazy overkill for something so simple.

Are there other options?

Comment: FWIW, I threw some AJAX into an mturk template to callback to my app to provide some recommended options based on data from the uploaded CSV. It really wasn't that bad to throw one AJAX call in there. It might be the most straightforward of these options. Another solution, if you really are just talking 10 workers and 10 tasks you want would just be to say you will only pay for one per worker and will reject multiple submissions. Most mturkers seem to follow directions from my experience.